# jQuery Datatable - Deleted Record Remains in the table

Tags: jquery, ajax, stored-procedures, datatables

Calling stored procedures to bind data to a jQuery Datatable (v1.10.16).  When deleting a record, the Ajax call successfully deletes the record from the database.  In the delete's Callback, I rebind the jQuery Datatable, but the record I just deleted remains.  If I refresh the page, the record I just deleted is no longer in the datatable.

```
 function DeleteFundingSource(id)
{       
     function callBack(response) {
        if (response.d == 'OK') {
            $('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').text("Funding Source Archived Successfully");
            if ($('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').hasClass("bg-danger"))
                $('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').removeClass("bg-danger");

            $('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').addClass("bg-success");

              GetFundingSources();  //rebind the grid
        }
        else {
            $('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').text(response.d);
            if ($('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').hasClass("bg-success"))
                $('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').removeClass("bg-success")
            $('#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>').addClass("bg-danger");

        }
     }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../services/Inv_WS.asmx/DeleteFundingSource',
        data: { ID: JSON.stringify(id) },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            callBack(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
            alert('Failed to load data in DataTable!');
        }
    });

}


 function GetFundingSources() {
     $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../services/Inv_WS.asmx/GetFundingSource',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
         success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                    body = "<tr>";
                    body += "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' title='Edit'></span></td>";
                    body += "<td>" + v.Name + "<input id='hidID' type='hidden' value='" + v.ID + "' ></td>";
                    body += "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' OnClick='DeleteFundingSource(" + v.ID + "); return false;' title='Delete'></span></td>";
                    body += "</tr>";
                    $("#tblFund tbody").append(body);
                });
            });

            /*DataTables instantiation.*/
           var t= $("#tblFund").DataTable();
           t.draw(true);

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            alert('Failed to load data in DataTable!');
        }
    });
}
```

I use the same approach when Adding a new record or Editing an existing record and these operations execute successfully and the datatable reflects changes accordingly.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: Did you cross check whether your ajax call is returning proper data after deletion?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

My approach of adding elements to the DOM was the problem.  Successfully resolved like this:

Outside of the scope of my functions I added a new variable:  var table;

```
 function GetFundingSources() {
    table = $("#tblFund").DataTable();
    table.clear();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../services/Inv_WS.asmx/GetFundingSource',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                    body = "<tr>";
                    body += "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' title='Edit'></span></td>";
                    body += "<td>" + v.Name + "<input id='hidID' type='hidden' value='" + v.ID + "' ></td>";
                    body += "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' OnClick='DeleteFundingSource(" + v.ID + "); return false;' title='Delete'></span></td>";
                    body += "</tr>";
                    table.row.add($(body).get(0)).draw(); 
                });
            });

        },
        error: function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
         //   alert('Failed to load data in DataTable!');
        }
    });
}
```

The key to the solution is the line:

```
table.row.add($(body).get(0)).draw();
```

Rather than adding elements to the DOM, this approach actually adds rows to the datatable.  Now the delete function works flawlessly.